# Using MvvmCross with Xamarin.Mac

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, mvvmcross, xamarin.mac

I tried to implement an OSX application using **Xamrin.Mac** and **MvvmCross v6.2.3**.

I successfully realized a basic example as described in [official documentation](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/getting-started/mvvmcross-overview) and in the [instructions](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/develop/ContentFiles) provided with the MvvmCross library.

I published my example on [github.com/riversx/MvvmCrossExample](https://github.com/riversx/MvvmCrossExample)

[image]

In this example the HomeViewModel works correctly but is presented in a separate window (Home.storyboard).

I would like to know if it is possible to link the HomeViewModel directly to the Main.storyboard/ViewController.

---

More details

In the 'Core' library project there is a class called HomeViewModel which contains the "business logic".

In the 'Mac' project there are two storyboards: Main.storyboard & Home.storyboard.

Main.storyboard is the one created while adding a new project from 'Cocoa App' template; Home.stotyboard is the one I created from scratch following the MvvmCross basic instructions for a Xamarin.Mac project.

Main.storyboard has a controller named ViewController which inherhits from NSViewController.

Home.storyboard has a controller named HomeView which inherhits from MvxViewController < HomeViewModel > (this is what I mean as 'link directly')

At startup both Views are presented.

To avoid the visualization of the empty window for Main.storyboard i tried to change the application main interface option.
But, if in Info.plist I set 'Home' as main interface I get an ArgumentNullException in HomeView.ViewDidLoad()

---

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean with, link directly? Please elaborate

Comment: Not too understand "link to the Main.storyboard/ViewController" ,This should need CustomRenderer to make a connection between them.

Comment: @Cheesebaron; I added more details, I hope this helps to understand better the issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @BorisSclauzero - did you ever figure this one out? I'm in a similar spot.

Comment: Hi @Adam, 
Sorry no useful response at the moment :(
My next step will be to use Electron.Net with Blazor app instead of Xamarin.Mac

Comment: Thanks @BorisSclauzero - Yeah, me too - I've been a Xamarin guy for a long time (since it was initially released in fact), but I'm spending my time these days getting familiar with Flutter. Xam Forms just doesn't deliver on the cross platform investment well enough.